# Pythons Social Auth for Spotify: redirect is missing 'state' parameter

Tags: python, django, oauth-2.0, spotify, python-social-auth

I am implementing Python Social Auth in a Django app that needs access to the user's Spotify account.  The initial step in the Auth flow works: a request is sent to Spotify's '/authorize' endpoint and the user is presented with a modal explaining the scopes of the access for which the app would be authorized. But, then when the app's redirect uri is requested ('/completed/spotify/') this exception is raised:

```
AuthMissingParameter at /complete/spotify/
Missing needed parameter state
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/complete/spotify/
Django Version: 1.8.2
Exception Type: AuthMissingParameter
Exception Value:    
Missing needed parameter state
Exception Location: /Users/brandon/Envs/group_playlist_generator/lib/python2.7/site-packages/social/backends/oauth.py in validate_state, line 86
Python Executable:  /Users/brandon/Envs/group_playlist_generator/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.9
Python Path:    
['/Users/brandon/dev/group_playlist_generator',
 '/Users/brandon/Envs/group_playlist_generator/lib/python27.zip',
 '/Users/brandon/Envs/group_playlist_generator/lib/python2.7',
 '/Users/brandon/Envs/group_playlist_generator/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin',
 '/Users/brandon/Envs/group_playlist_generator/lib/python2.7/plat-mac',
 '/Users/brandon/Envs/group_playlist_generator/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages',
 '/Users/brandon/Envs/group_playlist_generator/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/Users/brandon/Envs/group_playlist_generator/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/Users/brandon/Envs/group_playlist_generator/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages',
 '/Users/brandon/Envs/group_playlist_generator/lib/python2.7/site-packages']
```

This question may just be a function of my experience with Auth in general especially in the context of Django. I've read through relevant parts of PSA's source code but I do not understand how this 'state' parameter gets passed around between Spotify and the app. I see this param added to the original request to Spotify but I am not sure how to ensure it gets passed back to the redirect URI and/or if there are other considerations regarding 'state' such as storing it somewhere. Any advice is welcome.

Comment: Can you post your pipeline please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I've read through relevant parts of PSA's source code but I do not
> understand how this 'state' parameter gets passed around between
> Spotify and the app.

When using the Authorization Code flow or Implicit Grant flow in oAuth 2.0, an optional `state` value can be appended to the authorize URL. If a `state` is sent to the API provider, it's also appended in the response to the application making the request as part of the redirect. The purpose of `state` is to prevent [Cross Site Request Forgery](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-10.12) (CSRF) attacks.

From [Spotify's Authorization Guide](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-10.12) for the **Authorization Code** flow:

[image: Authorization Code flow and Spotify's Web API]

As you can see in the image, the state is sent to Spotify's Accounts Service in **#1**, and passed back to the Application in **#3**. At this point, the Application double-checks that the state has the same value as what was sent during **#1**. If it isn't the same value, someone has tried to access the Application's redirect URI directly instead of being redirected from Spotify's Accounts Service.

> I see this param added to the original request to Spotify but I am
> not sure how to ensure it gets passed back to the redirect URI

Given that you're on version 0.2.10 of Python Social Auth, the `state` parameter is read [here](https://github.com/omab/python-social-auth/blob/master/social/backends/oauth.py#L72), and the exception is raised [here](https://github.com/omab/python-social-auth/blob/master/social/backends/oauth.py#L86), so it looks like the `state` parameter is never passed back to your application. The only reason that it wouldn't be passed back is that `state` was never sent to Spotify's Accounts service. Please debug and double check that `state` is part of the response query parameters, and also that it's part of the request query parameters. If the request has a `state`, there should be a `state` set in the response as well. If Python Social Auth allows you to opt-out of using state, I'd try that at least for trouble-shooting.

Comment: Huge thanks. This helped me troubleshoot, but more importantly, helped me understand what is going on in the Auth flow. The actual exception seems to be a result of me defining a setting called LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL incorrectly and causing a second redirect to be fired after Spotify makes a request to my already defined redirect uri. This answer helped me discover that bug, so its more than acceptable. Thanks again.